# Duda Con Java En Linux Y En Windows

Tags: java, linux, windows, eclipse

Recién estoy aprendiendo en java,tengo una duda,
Estoy creando un programa en java que se va a usar en windows pero yo lo estoy creando en Linux mint,La pregunta es cuando vaya a usar el programa en windows le tendré que hacer algún cambio o me funcionara igual que en linux pregunto ya que son dos sistema operativo diferentes.

Comment: Java es multi plataforma

Comment: me causa duda, por que no hiciste la prueba antes? hubiera sido un método de solución mas rápido, intentar ejecutar tu programa y si presentaba fallas indicar cuales

Answer (score 2):

En realidad también depende de como se realice la programación y lo que hará el programa.

Me explico. Si por ejemplo en el programa abre un archivo y el programador ha puesto que este archivo estará en:

/home/miUsuario/elArchivo.txt

Pues el programa no funcionará sobre Windows pues en ese sistema operativo no existe esa ruta.

Otra, si por ejemplo estamos usando SWT para pintar el gráfico de nuestro programa y así sin más lo queremos ejecutar sobre Windows pues no va a funcionar pues se necesita la versión de la librería especial para trabajar sobre esta plataforma. Esto ocurre por que con Java en ocasiones se programa usando librerias que utilizan DDLs o .SO que son dependientes del Sistema Operativo donde se ejecute. Es por esta situación que programas java como el famoso IDE Eclipse se descargan especialmente para una plataforma.

Otra cosa más es el hecho de cuidar que la maquina virtual donde se ejecute el programa siempre tenga una versión mayor o igual a la versión con que se ha hecho la programación. Si por ejemplo el programa se construye usando Java 11 agregando uso de módulos (o alguna clase nueva que solo exista en esa versión de Java) pues esto no va a funcionar sobre Java 10 o cualquier versión inferior.

Answer (score 1):

Java es un lenguaje multiplataforma. Existen compiladores de Java para la mayoría de las plataformas e interpretes de Java para todas.
El funcionamiento del programa Java es el mismo en todas las plataformas y sólo cambia la apariencia que se adapta a la del sistema operativo que lo ejecuta (windows, solaris, linux, etc.)

Comment: Muchas Gracias, entonces tendría que funcionar como me funciono en linux, muchas Gracias